# AWK - change the file name (special characters)

Tags: awk

This command renames a file:

```
$ find $PWD -name "*.jpg" | awk '{c=$0; gsub("/", "_", c)}{system("mv -v " $0 " " c)}'
`/home/pic/Pulpit/test/stary/1.jpg' -> `_home_pic_Pulpit_test_stary_1.jpg'
```

I have a test file:

```
$ ls 
`[~!($%^_&*){.}\___"`]`1.jpg
```

.........

```
 $ find -not -name .
 ./`[~!($%^_&*){.}\___"`]`1.jpg
```

I want to change the file name:

```
$ find -not -name . | awk '{c=$0; gsub("/", "_", c)}{system("mv -v " $0 " " c)}'
/bin/sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I want:

```
_home_pic_Pulpit_test_stary_`[~!($%^_&*){.}\___"`]`1.jpg
```

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

This works to 'gawk', but it does not work on 'mawk'.

gawk (works):

```
$ find -not -name . | gawk '{ 
>     c=$0; 
>     gsub( "/", "_", c ); 
>     c = gensub( /([[:punct:]])/, "\\\\&", "g", c ); 
>     $0 = gensub( /([[:punct:]])/, "\\\\&", "g", $0 ); 
>     system("echo mv -v " $0 " " c)}
> '
mv -v ./`[~!($%^_&*){.}\___"`]`1.jpg ._`[~!($%^_&*){.}\___"`]`1.jpg
```

mawk (does not work):

```
$ find -not -name . | mawk '{ 
>     c=$0; 
>     gsub( "/", "_", c ); 
>     c = gensub( /([[:punct:]])/, "\\\\&", "g", c ); 
>     $0 = gensub( /([[:punct:]])/, "\\\\&", "g", $0 ); 
>     system("echo mv -v " $0 " " c)}
> '
mawk: line 8: function gensub never defined
mawk: line 8: function gensub never defined
```

gawk (works):

```
$ find -not -name . | gawk '{
>     gsub( /[[:punct:]]/, "\\\\&" ); 
>     c = $0; 
>     gsub( /\//, "_", c ); 
>     system( "echo mv -v " $0 " " c ) }
> '
mv -v ./`[~!($%^_&*){.}\___"`]`1.jpg ._`[~!($%^_&*){.}\___"`]`1.jpg
```

mawk (does not work):

```
$ find -not -name . | mawk '{
>     gsub( /[[:punct:]]/, "\\\\&" ); 
>     c = $0; 
>     gsub( /\//, "_", c ); 
>     system( "echo mv -v " $0 " " c ) }
> '
/bin/sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 and I have installed 'mawk'.

How to do it on 'mawk'?

**EDIT - 1:**

On another forum I got a solution for mawk.

```
find $PWD -name "*.jpg" | mawk 'a=$0{gsub("/", "_")}{system("mv -v '"'"'" a "'"'"' '"'"'" $0 "'"'"'")}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `GNU awk`. I escape all punctuation characters before executing the `mv` command.

```
find -not -name . | awk '{ 
    c=$0; 
    gsub( "/", "_", c ); 
    c = gensub( /([[:punct:]])/, "\\\\&", "g", c ); 
    $0 = gensub( /([[:punct:]])/, "\\\\&", "g", $0 ); 
    system("mv -v " $0 " " c)}
'
```

---

**UPDATE** to add an `awk` compatible command:

```
find -not -name . | awk '{
    gsub( /[[:punct:]]/, "\\\\&" ); 
    c = $0; 
    gsub( /\//, "_", c ); 
    system( "mv -v " $0 " " c ) }
'
```

Comment: See my edit.

Thank you for your response.

This works to 'gawk', but it does not work on 'mawk'.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 and I have installed 'mawk'.

How to do it on 'mawk'?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your solution works for gawk. On another forum I got a solution for mawk. `find $PWD -name "*.jpg" | mawk 'a=$0{gsub("/", "_")}{system("mv -v '"'"'" a "'"'"' '"'"'" $0 "'"'"'")}'`

Comment: @Tedee12345: Thank you. I had no clue about that error with `mawk`. Glad that you solved it :-)